# Asignar una imagen que reemplace al android:src="@drawable/imagen", por JAVA

Tags: java, android

Como puedo asignar la imagen que tengo en esta ruta en el celular (almacenamiento interno - ***NO SD***): **Android/data/com.example.juan/files/Pictures/Imagen;** intente con esto **String uri = "Android/data/com.example.juan/files/Pictures/Imagen";** pero me cierra la app

```
            String uri = "@drawable/imagen";
            int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
            Drawable img = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), imageResource);
            imgviewtomarfoto.setImageDrawable(img);
```

Comment: Hola estas pidiendo el permiso para acceso al almacenamiento ?

Comment: Tal vez tienes malentendidos, esto es incorrecto:  String uri = "@drawable/imagen"; , comenta ¿donde tienes almacenada la imagen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si estas en un dispositivo con sistema operativo android 6.0 a más deberías solicitar los permisos para poder utilizar el almacenamiento, luego para poder acceder a a la ruta de las imagenes alojadas en el dispositivo podrias usar esto

```
File imgFile = new  File("ruta");
if(imgFile.exists()){
   Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
   ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
   myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Agrega este permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: No es suficiente agregar el permiso en el AndroidManifest.xml